# Is Porofessor a cheat in League Of Legends? [Jungle Timers reveal enemy jg location in non-vision?]

Tags: league-of-legends, cheats

I've been using a legitimate app called Porofessor that provides a lot of helpful info when playing league of legends, such as displaying objective / jungle camp timers when things will respawn (such as dragon, baron, jungle camps etc), showing player histories like champ statistics, win rates, etc, and also suggests runes and can auto-fill them into your slots to make it easier to prep for a match.

The jungle timers in the app will go off for camps the player doesn't have vision of, for example often times i'll see a camp on the opponents side suddenly show a timer, and will realize that their jg must have just cleared it and is in that location, even though i've got no vision there.

Update - I was wrong; apparently it was showing them when a camp was about to respawn, at 60's , not when it was just killed. So I would be recognizing that the JG *should be there soon* rather than just cleared it. Coincidence

Comment: Note this question is currently being considered to be closed because it may only be answered with opinions and not facts, but the accepted answer suggests otherwise. It would be beneficial if OP can clarify the objective aspects of this question.

Comment: @54D I think it's answered; the answer provided an explanation of what is and isn't considered acceptable in the game which answered what I was looking for.

Comment: I am aware, it was only a suggestion to prevent this answer from being closed -- reviewers may not always look at existing answers and be convinced that this is a question answerable with facts. Either way it looks fine to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Yes, it's cheating

From [this page](https://support-leagueoflegends.riotgames.com/hc/en-us/articles/225266848) on third party applications:

> We don’t like applications that provide measurable player advantage. We’d like to set fair expectations by calling out some features that definitely aren’t okay. Some examples of measurable player advantage:
>
> - Exposing information that’s intentionally obfuscated (cooldowns or timers)

Based on those quoted sections, this would be considered cheating. You're only supposed to know jungle timers if you see the camp being cleared; seeing a timer after the enemy jungler has cleared a camp outside of your team's vision is not okay. You should report it to the Porofessor developers so they can make changes to the jungle timer overlay.

There's a [Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/leagueoflegends/comments/pyfcpv/the_blitz_app_jungle_timers_is_cheating/) about the Blitz app, which provides similar functionality and had what seems to be the same issue. One of the comments says:

> Blitz employee here. The jungle timers should be fixed now. Thank you for bringing this to our attention.

That suggests there are actions that the Porofessor developers can take to not provide timers for camps cleared outside of your team's vision.

Comment: I ended up submitting a note to the developer with an explanation - I'm pretty sure it's a bug around, once your jungle has seen the opposing camp once, you then get the timer for the rest of the match, even without vision, then the next time the timer resets or afterwards you have an advantage... definitely not ok

Comment: Or perhaps it's some other mechanic and i'm just not noticing what's leading up to it appearing.. not entirely sure.